# Extract email from the webpage in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to know what will be the way to extract email address from the page where it is not obvious in the html. e.g. in the page "http://www.hotfrog.com.au/business/Blacktrac/SendEmail.aspx?company=Blacktrac" i want to know what email address the message is sent to when we click "Send Email" button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The email is handled server side which means you will never be able to tell from the page what email your details were sent to.

Comment: then can you please tell me, how can i simulate the request that is sent on email button when clicked in the above url?